# Hibernate get single row from the table with maximum field value

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hql

In Hibernate, how can I get single row from the table with maximum field value?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Using Custom Query](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html)

Table Structure:

> ID    insurance_name  invested_amount investement_date

```
public class HibernateHQLMaxFunction {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Session sess = null;
    try {
      SessionFactory fact = new 
      Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
      sess = fact.openSession();
      String SQL_QUERY = "select 
max(FIELD_NAME)from Insurance insurance";
        Query query = sess.createQuery(SQL_QUERY);
        List list = query.list();
        System.out.println("Max 
Invested Amount: " + list.get(0));   
      sess.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

from [here](http://www.roseindia.net/hibernate/hibernate-max.shtml)